# Pass JavaScript values to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I need to pass JavaScript values and insert them in database via PHP. I have tried over the URL but it does not work.

Two variables needs to be inserted.

All values from database are printed in table, then I make selection.

The name of this file is items.php.

```
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantity" placeholder="" ></td>
<td><center><button type="submit"  onclick="myFunction()" value="<?php echo 'R-' . $id_print ;?>" id="item"> <i class="icon-cart"></i></button></center></td>
```

I use this script to get values:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
        var y = document.getElementById("item").value;

        window.location.href = "items?w1=" + x + "&w2=" + y;
    }
</script>
```

I do not know why script does not redirect to another URL with values from the script.

I get both values when debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a `<button>` element has `type="submit"`, clicking it submits the form, and therefore prevents execution of JavaScript click event handler assigned to this element. You should change its `type` to `button`, so it won't submit the form.

Corrected code:

```
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantity" placeholder="" ></td>
<td><center><button type="button"  onclick="myFunction()" value="<?php echo 'R-' . $id_print ;?>" id="item"> <i class="icon-cart"></i></button></center></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use html-forms.
Because input-values are sent automatically when submit.
Look like this (not tested):

```
<!-- your html -->
<form action="items" method="post">
   <!-- your table -->
   <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantity" name="w1" /></td>
   <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="item" name="w2" value="<?php echo 'R-' . $id_print ;?>" onclick="this.form.submit()" /></td>
</form>
```